# Grammar difference between "Drive Home" vs" "Drive to Work"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was configuring my navigation recently and came across this thought and I'm not sure I understand the grammatical rules as to why it is proper to say "Drive Home" but not "Drive to Home". It seems to make sense to say "Drive to My Home" but certainly not "Drive My Home".

Likewise, why is it "Drive to Work" but not "Drive Work" (aside from the obvious different meaning). I get that "Go Work" is different here since Work is also a verb, but "Go to Home" doesn't sound right.

It makes sense to me that "to" should be required as a preposition to a destination, but what makes "Home" different?

Comment: See the linked question and the related questions linked from there. In brief, you are looking at two different parts of speech. *Home* is not necessarily always a noun. Just like *work* isn't, for that matter.